# Adding custom/user-defined metadata to images/photos?

Tags: metadata, photo, exif, xmp, user-defined

I'm writing some software that will need to add custom fields to images/photos.  Specifically for iOS/OS X, but the ideal solution would be some industry-standard or platform-agnostic way of doing it.

EXIF's Comments field isn't really viable because many photo management/photo editing apps allow the user to edit that field directly.

Currently my only reasonable solution is to use XMP sidecar files and add custom tags there, since the XMP officially requires each app reading XMP to ignore whatever tags it doesn't understand.

The problem with this on Apple platforms is that the XMP file is used for storing edits/deltas off the original image, and it may be the case that the Photos framework assumes it completely owns the file and could delete the entire file under certain circumstances.

Does anyone know of any alternative to this that is better-suited?

Any help would be extremely appreciated.  Even personal opinions at this point may be of help.

Comment: Have you considered [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/examples.html)?

Comment: EXIF is a non-starter because the standard doesn't allow for custom fields.

Comment: Sure it does. Exif doesn't define them, but the container format TIFF allows you to store your own custom fields.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have some private data to be stored. To store those images in Photos app, Apple asks user to send images as a Dictionary. I cannot use exifmakernote key because Apply has a separate MakerAppleDictionary that it reads and ignores the other key. I can use User comment field but it would render compatibility with my app specific tools NULL if the data is overwritten. Can the AppleMakerNote be replaced? (although, it is available only iOS7 and above)\

Comment: I am asking iif it against Apple's rules, if I add some additional keys.